# React State one state behind

Tags: reactjs, react-native, setstate

So I am having a very minimal program where on click of TouchableOpacity I add an item to my array. So the code for same looks like

```
  // Initial state is []
  onClick = () => {
    this.setState(
      {
        arr: this.state.arr.concat({a: 1, b: 2}),
      },
      console.log(this.state.arr), // gives []
    );
  };
```

The console.log in the callback function for setState is behind one state. And on nextClick it gives the state as `[{"a": 1, "b": 2}]`. So how can I get the current updated state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing `console.log(...)` inside a **callback**. Try the following :-

```
  onClick = () => {
    this.setState(
      {
        arr: this.state.arr.concat({a: 1, b: 2}),
      },
      ()=>console.log(this.state.arr), //
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you intend to pass a *callback* as a second argument but now you call `console.log` directly.

Just change it to `() => console.log(this.state.arr),`